# Implementing a linked list: head insertion and destructor

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

I have done this:

```
class Node {
  //
  int key;
  Node* next;

public:

  //
  Node() : key( -1 ), next( NULL ) {}
  Node( int i, Node* j ) : key( i ), next( j ) {}
  //
  ~Node() { delete next; }

  //
  static void head_insertion( Node* & head, int i );
  void print_list();
};


void Node::head_insertion( Node* & head, int i ) {


  cout << "insert() 1 head = " << head << endl; 
  // append the current list to n
  Node n(i, head);
  cout << "address of n = " << &n << endl;
  // make n the new head
  head = &n;
  //

  cout << "insert() 2 head = " << head << endl; 
}
```

Head insertion doesn't work:

```
insert() 1 head = 0x7fff56821518
address of n = 0x7fff56821518
insert() 2 head = 0x7fff56821518
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have two questions:

- The newly created Node `n` in `head_insertion` has the same address as the address pointed at by `head`. What's going on?
- I wrote the destructor thinking that there would be recursive calls to the destructors of elements next in the list. Is this correct?

Comment: You're "adding" a local instance variable to your list. You need to dynamically allocate a new `Node`; not push a local-scope instance. Once that scope is left, that object is gone and access to it is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: how you are calling head_insertion()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in `void Node::head_insertion( Node* & head, int i )`:

```
Node n(i, head);
cout << "address of n = " << &n << endl;
// make n the new head
head = &n;
```

Should be:

```
Node *pn = new Node(i, head);
cout << "address of n = " << pn << endl;
// make n the new head
head = pn;
```

And the destructor `~Node() { delete next; }` cause broken link, should be avoid.

And more...
The whole design is causing problem.

What your class is to implement a Node, so do what a Node should do.

```
class Node {
  int key;
  Node* next;

public:

  Node() : key( -1 ), next( NULL ) {}
  Node( int i, Node* j ) : key( i ), next( j ) {}
  //
  ~Node() { }   // don't delete the next node here! Not the job of this object.


  void print_node();
};

class Linklist {
    Node *head;
public:
    Linklist(): head(0) {}
    static void head_insertion( Linklist & list, int i );
    void print_list();
    〜Linklist();       // traverse your list node and do the deletion here
}
```

Put things supposed to be done by list level to handle by class Linklist.

Answer (score 1):

You did not use dynamic memory to allocate `n`.  On the first pass through, it gets added to the list, the function then ends and `n` goes out of scope.  On the second pass, it happens to come up in the same position on the stack, yielding the same pointer

Answer (score 0):

In the function `void Node::head_insertion( Node* & head, int i )` you are creating a automatic variable `Node n()` whose lifetime is within the function scope, So outside the `head_insertion` function if you want to access that node you will get `segmentation fault` because that memory area you no longer own.
To prevent that you may dynamically create object :

```
Node* n = new Node(i,head)
```

About your last question: **Even if you don't write destructor of your own the compiler will provide you a default version**. I guess the destructor is not calling destractor so why should be recursion.